# When a UWP folder is considered cloud backed, where exactly is that cloud?

Tags: windows, uwp, cloud

I am trying to understand the specifics of cloud backed in the UWP context on Windows 10.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata?view=winrt-22000

According to the documentation, the folder LocalFolder is "cloud back". What cloud is it backed to? Do users need an account? Is there unlimited storage available?

Answer (score 0):

I belive any backed up data is stored in OneDrive.

The storage available depends on your subscription: https://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/microsoft-365/onedrive/compare-onedrive-plans?activetab=tab%3Aprimaryr1

Comment: I bought OneDrive to test it out. OneDrive only backs up Desktop, Documents, and Pictures. Nothing from the UWP apps is backed up.

Comment: Yes, but you don't see it in your ordinary OneDrive folder.